# Is there a method to get last month name and year in C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

`DateTime.Now.ToString("Y")` returns me :   August 2013

Is there an easy method to get last month in the same format?

Something like : `DateTime.LastMonth.ToString("Y")` and output will be : July 2013

I know this method doesnt exists :) but maybe there is something else to achieve that output? Or I will need to create my own method for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not use [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

For example:

```
var lastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("Y");`
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to be a static method of DateTime?

Comment: get it I shoudl use Now too :)

Comment: Correct, it wouldn't be a static method, it works on instantiated DateTime's only, which is what DateTime.Now returns.

Answer (score 9):

You can add or subtract months from a given date by using [`DateTime.AddMonths()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)

```
var lastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var lastMonthAsString = lastMonth.ToString("Y");
```

The same exists for other time intervals like `AddDays()`, `AddSeconds()` or `AddYears()`. You can find all available methods at [MSDN's DateTime documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_methods.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use extension methods...Maybe something along the lines...

```
public static string LastMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
return DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("Y");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get abbreviated month name, you can below lines,

```
DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
string Month  =     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(lastMonth.Month)    ;
```